# How can i start a new line in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = good;
```

I want to start writing on new line when using this function for the second time

Comment: + use `+=` instead of `=` if you want to add some content instead of overwriting it

Comment: dont make it complex simply use different <p> or <div> tags for entering in different line

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would recommend:

1. Define the element once at the beginning to save getting it every time.
2. Create a custom function called `print()` which you can call more easily.
3. Use `+=` to add and not overwrite content.
4. Use `br` elements to add line breaks after each printed message.

```js
printDiv = document.getElementById("print");

function print(text) {
  printDiv.innerHTML += text + '<br>';
}

print('This text');
print('is just here');
print('to test the function');
```

```html
<div id="print"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating HTML.

A new line in HTML is usually created with a [`<br>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).

That might not be the right option for the data you are generating though. HTML is a semantic markup language so you should generate the markup that describes the semantics of the data you are working with.

That might involve creating a list with list items in it, multiple paragraphs, or something else.